# NumPy - Selecting a submatrix from another 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, math, linear-algebra

This is my original 2d array **A**

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 2, 2, 8, 8, 8, 2, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 2, 2, 8, 8, 8, 2, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Let's say I want to return a **3x3** submatrix of 8's at the middle. I made a boolean mask with this expression `A == 8` and it looks like this.

```
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False]])
```

This is the point where I'm stuck. How can I return the submatrix with that boolean mask? If I do `A[A == 8]`, it returns a flat array of 8s like this

```
array([8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8])
```

Another way is getting the row and column numbers with `np.where(A == 8)` which returns `(array([5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7]), array([3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5]))`. How can I return the matrix using them?

Is there any better approach for this problem?

Comment: Boolean indexing like this returns a 1d result.  In general such indexing does not a return a neat block of values.  But if you know the results will be such block, just reshape them.

Comment: @hpaulj I don't know the shape

Comment: It works as intended, because you don't always have rectangular shape, eg. `A[A==2]`. Now if you are certain that `8` only appear in a block, you can detect the shape with `argmin/argmax`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, `A[A==some_value]` correctly returns a rank-1 array of values `some_value`. That makes sense because it's not always the case that the values `some_value` are organized in a block (take for example `some_value = 2`) or the number of values `some_value` is such that they cannot be put into a 2D array.

However If you are sure that there is such a block, you can do the following to get it:

```
import numpy as np

inds = np.where(A==8)
slice_x = slice(inds[0].min(), inds[0].max() + 1)  # slice(6, 9, None)
slice_y = slice(inds[1].min(), inds[1].max() + 1)  # slice(3, 6, None)

A[slice_x, slice_y]

# array([[8, 8, 8],
#        [8, 8, 8],
#        [8, 8, 8]])
```

As alternative, you can use `scipy.ndimage.find_objects` to obtain the slices:

```
from scipy import ndimage

slice_x, slice_y = ndimage.find_objects(A==8)[0]  # (slice(6, 9, None), slice(3, 6, None))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can capture `row` and `column` indexes and after that return submatrix from these indexes only using [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) method:

```
x, y = np.where(A==8) #[5 5 5 6 6 6 7 7 7], [3 4 5 3 4 5 3 4 5]
x, y = np.unique(x), np.unique(y) # [5,6,7], [3,4,5]
print(A[np.ix_(x, y)]) #prints [[8 8 8], [8 8 8], [8 8 8]]
```

This should work even in more general cases, although not always as expected:

```
def submatrix(A):
    x, y = np.where(A==8)
    x, y = np.unique(x), np.unique(y)
    return A[np.ix_(x, y)]

>>> A = np.array([
[8, 2, 8, 2, 8, 0],
[2, 8, 8, 8, 2, 0],
[2, 8, 4, 8, 3, 0],
[0, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0],
[8, 0, 8, 0, 8, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
>>> submatrix(A)
array([[8, 2, 8, 2, 8],
       [2, 8, 8, 8, 2],
       [2, 8, 4, 8, 3],
       [0, 8, 8, 8, 0],
       [8, 0, 8, 0, 8]])
>>> A = np.array([
[8, 2, 8, 2, 8, 0],
[2, 2, 8, 8, 2, 0],
[2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 0],
[0, 2, 8, 8, 0, 0],
[8, 0, 8, 0, 8, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
>>> submatrix(A) # skipping empty rows and columns
array([[8, 8, 2, 8],
       [2, 8, 8, 2],
       [0, 8, 8, 0],
       [8, 8, 0, 8]])
```

Since `np.unique` returns sorted arrays, you can fill the gaps constucting `x`, `y` like so:

```
def submatrix(A):
    x, y = np.where(A==8)
    x, y = np.unique(x), np.unique(y)
    x, y = np.arange(x[0], x[-1]+1), np.arange(y[0], y[-1]+1)
    return A[np.ix_(x, y)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
 data = A[np.any(A==8,axis=1)]
 data.T[np.all(data==8,axis=0)]
```

This should give,

```
 array([[8, 8, 8],
        [8, 8, 8],
        [8, 8, 8]])
```